# Which adjective explains a general spring problem better?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm checking the balancer springs of an industrial machine in one step of a flowchart where the follow-up decision question asks if the springs are "problematic" (?). I couldn't decide on a single general adjective to include every type of spring fault. I've googled "faulty", "broken", "problematic", "damaged", and "defective". I'm leaning towards "faulty" and "defective".

Which one describes and combines all possible spring problems? Are there other better adjectives to describe it?

Comment: A spring problem might not be a fault, and it might not be a defect, but it will be a problem: therefore use 'problematic', as your own phrasing ("describes and combines all possible spring problems") suggests.

Comment: Good point. I'll wait for a few extra comments/answers and then use your suggestion. I can select and vote it up if you write it as an answer.

Comment: What JEL said. **Problematic** is used for problems of all kind.

Comment: I might just use “check springs” for one flowchart box and “Problem?” for the other.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to cram too much stuff into that box.

Comment: @HotLicks The "control" step checks if the springs are the reason for a machine balancing problem. It's just a simple control step but the problem can be caused by many different types of spring defects (maybe "defective" the right adjective!). Most of the other steps have a common, simple checkpoint question whereas some decision boxes like this one are hard to formulate. The defect/fault/problem types for springs seem to be as broad as : broken, faulty, defective, loose, rigid, misplaced, etc. I'm going to use the recommendation (problematic) by NVZ and JEL to satisfy all of the above.

Comment: But how does one know that a specific spring behavior is a problem, without it being, to some degree, itemized?  The spring could be weak, it could be bent, it could be crusted/jammed with corrosion or mud.  If multiple springs must be "in balance", a single spring may be perfectly fine, just not "matched" to it's partner, so the mechanism that is supported sits lop-sided.

Comment: @HotLicks This is the job of the control step. The technician is going to check for all types of spring defects/faults/combined misbalancing/etc in the control step and then go on to the next step by answering the decision question which has 2 outcomes: there was some kind of a spring problem or not. My original problem was to find out a one word decision term to cover all bases which seems to be "problematic".

Comment: *Problematic*  is used to describe something that causes or introduces a problem.  I don’t think that’s your intent here.

Comment: If you place a bounty on your question, it will get noticed more and answered better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problematic** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/problematic)

> Posing a problem; difficult to solve
>   *"a repair that proved more problematic than first expected."*

*Problematic* is applicable to all kinds of problems, so it's the best option here. Other words you suggested are all specific and aren't applicable everywhere.